# Inputs from QFormLayout are printing empty

Tags: python, pyqt5

My program collecting some data from the user (patient ID, trial no., activity, etc.) using a dialog window with a QFormLayout. I want to save these data and print them onto the main window, but when I print them they come out empty. I'm new to Python so I'm wondering if there's a structural issue with my code that is causing the variables to be lost.

I have a main class for the main window that looks like this (there is more but I cut out irrelevant parts):

```
 class App(QMainWindow):
    """ Sets up the main window for the Graphical User Interface """
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Title'
        self.left = 60
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 1400
        self.height = 820
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self) : 
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        
        *lots of labels and buttons added here*

        inputs = getInputs()
        inputs.exec()
        patID = inputs.patID
        patAct = inputs.patAct
        patTrial = inputs.patTrial

        # print out inputs under their labels
        label_pat2 = QLabel(str(patID), self)
        label_pat2.move(150, 200)
        
        label_activity2 = QLabel(str(patAct), self)
        label_activity2.move(300, 200)
        
        label_trial2= QLabel(str(patTrial), self)
        label_trial2.move(500, 200)

        self.show() # show main window
```

Then I have another class that opens a dialog window to get the inputs, which looks like this:

```
class getInputs(QDialog):
    """ Takes in the patient ID number, trial number, and patient activity """
    # NumGridRows = 3
    # NumButtons = 4
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # super(getInputs, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()
        
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Trial information Input Dialog")
        self.resize(400,200)
        
    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        combo_box = QComboBox()
        combo_box.addItem("Walking")
        combo_box.addItem("Running")
        combo_box.addItem("Slow Walking")
        
        line_edit = QLineEdit()
        spin_box = QSpinBox()
        
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Patient ID:"), line_edit)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Activity:"), combo_box)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Trial no.:"), spin_box)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.patID = line_edit.text() 
        self.patAct = combo_box.currentText()
        self.patTrial = spin_box.text()
```

My theories right now are that there is either an error in my structure that causes the results from the window to be deleted, or that the .text() and .currentText() functions might not be the right function to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the data an instant after creating the widgets when the user still does not interact with the QDialog. On the other hand, to obtain the value of the QSpinBox you must use the value() method:

```py
class getInputs(QDialog):
    """Takes in the patient ID number, trial number, and patient activity"""

    # NumGridRows = 3
    # NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # super(getInputs, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Trial information Input Dialog")
        self.resize(400, 200)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.combo_box = QComboBox()
        self.combo_box.addItem("Walking")
        self.combo_box.addItem("Running")
        self.combo_box.addItem("Slow Walking")

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.spin_box = QSpinBox()

        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Patient ID:"), self.line_edit)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Activity:"), self.combo_box)
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Trial no.:"), self.spin_box)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    def exec(self):
        super().exec()
        self.patID = self.line_edit.text()
        self.patAct = self.combo_box.currentText()
        self.patTrial = self.spin_box.value()
```